# Change font size of a part of a div (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = days + ' ';
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += 'days ' + hours + ' hrs ';
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += minutes + ' mins ';
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += seconds + ' secs';

var x = document.getElementsByClassName('timer');
var index;
index = x.indexOf('');

for (var i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
    x[i].style.fontSize="40px";
}
```

I have the code above and I want to change the font size of the first word, but this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas to how I can do it?

Comment: Your code is not clear, what is `str` and where is your HTML?

Comment: I changed _str_ to _x_. Sorry, that was a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the first word in a separate tag:

```js
days = 12, hours = 23, minutes = 34, seconds = 45

document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = '<span style="font-size:40px">' + days + '</span> days ' + hours + ' hrs ' + minutes + ' mins ' + seconds + ' secs';
```

```html
<div id="countdown" class="timer" style="text-align: center;color: #366c18; letter-spacing: 2px; font-family: 'Christmas2'"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the font size of part of a text, you need to wrap the text in some kind of element, for instance a `<span>`. Then you can set the font size on the span with:

```
span.style.fontSize = '20px'
```

Comment: `<div id="countdown" class="timer" style="text-align: center;color: #366c18; letter-spacing: 2px; font-family: 'Christmas2'"></div>` This is the div of what I'm trying to modify.